# Can I change "ft_min_word_len" on shared hosting?

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have MySQL on shared hosting. Is there any way how to change value of `ft_min_word_len` without administrator access?

I found one workaround, where every word that has less than 4 characters is supplemented with _ or some other char, and the same is done with every searched keyword that is less than 4 characters.

Is there any better, or *cleaner* way to make Fulltext search work for short words?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Unfortunately, ft_min_word_len is a global system variable and cannot be set dynamically: see [MySQL's online docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html). Changing it would mean rebuilding every `FULLTEXT` index around, btw, so you can see why they don't want non-admins to mess with it.

I fear your workaround (or something entirely equivalent) is the only way to solve the problem in your situation. Sorry! (But, compliments for thinking of it!).

Comment: *If* you had administrator privileges: I haven't tested this, but if your data is static presumably you could set `ft_min_word_len = 1` temporarily, restart the server, build your database and index, and when you're done reset `ft_min_word_len` and restart again. Your database would then be left with the index you want?

Comment: I use xampp, how can I find `ft_min_word_len` ?

Comment: @Sajad, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706182/xampp-mysql-setting-ft-min-word-len

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but if someone has shell access to the server (even as non root) and mysql client tools you could do

```
myisamchk --recover --ft_min_word_len=2 mytable.MYI
```

Anyway you propably have to schedule this to run every day to include new values, too.