# match against not making sense

Tags: mysql, match

This is my filter text:

> Oliver used book

If I search for 'Oliver' it works, if I search for 'book' it works but if I search for 'used' it does not work.

> Heater white fan HEOP1322

```
Heater -> works : white -> works : fan -> does not work : HEOP -> does not work : HEOP1322 -> works.
```

My query is like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(filter) AGAINST ('fan' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(filter) AGAINST ('HEOP' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH(filter) AGAINST ('used' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Why d'hell does the word `used` not work and the word `book` works? They have the same length.

I also tried this suggestions [Mysql search for string and number using MATCH() AGAINST()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14572375/mysql-search-for-string-and-number-using-match-against) without success.

**Edit**: Solved, follow this instructions.
[XAMPP MySQL - Setting ft_min_word_len](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706182/xampp-mysql-setting-ft-min-word-len)

Comment: Remove `PHP` from the title. Your question isn't related to PHP

Comment: fancyPants did it for me. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

"used" is one of the default MySQL full text stopwords: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html. Stopwords are words which are ignored because they are too frequent in the (English) language and would not positively contribute to the result of a *full text* search. If you're only querying for single words, a `LIKE %..%` query may be more suited than a full-blown full text search.

Comment: Ok that answers one problem. I also read that the minimum lenght is 4, and to ignore it I should use + before the word. `+fan` continues not to work.