# Can I change MySQL ft_min_word_len on a specific database or table?

Tags: mysql

How can I change `ft_min_word_len` only for a specific database or table? Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: I have written a blog post on how this can be done http://www.linux-hosting.net/article/setting-minimum-length-indexed-words-3-mysql-ft_min_word_len

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL's `ft_min_word_len` is [a global server-system variable](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) and cannot be separately set for individual databases or tables.
As a workaround, as suggested in [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024456/how-to-change-ft-min-word-len), you could "pad" each word and search with some placeholder value.

Answer (score 0):

It is a database parameter, it cannot store the values for defined schemes or tables.
Here you can see how it should be changing for DB server : http://www.tiplib.com/117/change-ft_min_word_len-variable