# mysql - setting the ft_min_word_len to 2 via console

Tags: mysql, sql, console, putty

OK, I have SSH'd into my mysql console via PuTTY. Anyways, I'm in.

I do this because the database I'm on is shared hosting. I don't have access to the `my.ini` file.

How do I set `ft_min_word_len` to `2`. Its current, default value is `4`. How do I change it via mysql console?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this post [Can I change "ft_min_word_len" on shared hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024456/how-to-change-ft-min-word-len) you can't set that without admin privileges.  Also setting the full text min length to 2 will degrade full text performance and cause a lot of stop words to be searched.